# How to efficiently insert citations into LaTeX document with helm-bibtex?

Tags: latex, helm-bibtex

I'm having a heck of a time optimizing my desired `\cite` behavior when writing LaTeX source in emacs using helm-bibtex. I made a `C-c [` key-binding to get helm-bibtex going when I want to insert a citation:

```
(autoload 'helm-bibtex "helm-bibtex" "" t)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c [") 'helm-bibtex-with-local-bibliography)
```

What I want then is once I press `C-c [`, I want to start typing the name of a bib key, and when the entry is highlighted, I want to press `Enter` and it should insert the block `\cite{mykey}` into the text.

However the current process is so inefficient, I have to do `C-c [`, start typing until entry is highlighted, press `F3`, and then it asks me which kind of citation command I want where `cite` is the default, then it asks for "prenotes", then "postnotes", then FINALLY it inserts the cite block.

How do I get the behavior described first where I just press enter and it inserts cite block, instead of having to press a function key and `Enter` 3 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way to stop `helm-bibtex` from asking which kind of citation you want. You can stop it from asking you for prenotes and postnotes:

```lisp
(setq  bibtex-completion-cite-prompt-for-optional-arguments nil)
```

You can also make inserting a citation the default action:

```lisp
(helm-delete-action-from-source "Insert Citation" helm-source-bibtex)
(helm-add-action-to-source "Insert Citation" 
                           'helm-bibtex-insert-citation 
                            helm-source-bibtex 0)
```

This will automatically insert a citation when you hit enter, so you don't need to select it with `f3`.

With these values set, I can enter a new citation via:

1. `M-x helm-bibtex` (or your keybinding)
2. search for the entry
3. hit enter twice

That saves you two keypresses. I agree it would be nice to have `helm-bibtex` default to adding `cite`, without having to select it. It seems like there should be a way to configure this, but I don't see it.

Comment: The issue I'm seeing when I try this is I get the error `Wrong type argument: sequencep, 122` where the 122 is the ascii char number for `z` which is the first letter of the bibtex item key I selected on pressing Enter the first time in your Step 3. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Sorry, pasted the wrong code. Try the edited version

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, definitely far more efficient than the original.

Comment: Great solution! It works on Emacs 28